# Sending an image between elements

Tags: flutter

I am sending an image to my `PhotoPreviewScreen` once the photo is taken here on my `camera` page via this button:

```
onPressed: () async {
                var result = await controller.takePicture();
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => PhotoPreviewScreen(
                              imagePath: result.path,
```

However, I want to then be able to send this to my homepage in a gridview from my `PhotoPreview Screen` after clicking this button:

```
OutlineButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            var result = widget.imagePath;
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => PhotoPreviewScreen(
                          imagePath: result.path,
```

However, this is not successful. I have tried to define these elements on the `PhotoPreview Screen` through these items

```
class _PhotoPreviewScreenState extends State<PhotoPreviewScreen> {
  var image;
  String imgPath;

  Future _openGallery() async {
    if (widget.setData != null) {
      widget.setData(File(image.path));
    }
  }
```

Where am I going wrong and how could I refactor this code?
To summarize, the flow is:

1. Send photo upon picture taken to `PhotoPreviewScreen` (complete)
2. Intake photo on `PhotoPreviewScreen` (Complete)
3. Send photo to `GridView` on my `Homepage` after clicking button specified above (guidance required)

Here is the `GridView` which I need to send the image to upon button click

```
: GridView.count(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          crossAxisCount: 2,
                          crossAxisSpacing: 25,
                          mainAxisSpacing: 25,
                          childAspectRatio: (80 / 150),
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                          children:
                              List.generate(widget.imageArray.length, (index) {
                            return Container(
                              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                color: const Color(0xff000000),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                image: new DecorationImage(
                                  image: FileImage(widget.imageArray[index]),
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                  colorFilter: new ColorFilter.mode(
                                      Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4),
                                      BlendMode.dstATop)
```

Here is relevant piece of homepage in addition to the above:

```
class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<File> imageArray;
  Homepage({Key key, this.imageArray}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomepageState createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  var image;
```